# Как вывести картинку средствами opengl в linux

Tags: c, c++, opengl

Есть файл картинки например в *.bmp. Как показать ее на форме(создана с помошью glut). Не могу разобраться самостоятельно. Покажите пример кода или дайте сылку простых исходников где это используется. Желательно конечно чтобы можно было как можно больше форматов картинок загружать. Обязательно надо чтобы работало под linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно загрузить файл обычным образом, а затем отобразить вызовом функции [glDrawPixels](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml).

```
glDrawPixels(width, height, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
```

**Дополнено.**

Если нужно читать bmp, то это просто: `fopen/fread/fclose` и т.п. При этом выделение массива пикселей происходит согласно формату файла. Чтение произвольной графики стандартными средствами не осуществить, нужно подключать внешнюю библиотеку. Можно взять [FreeImage](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml), [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php), [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/), [CImg Library](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/), [Boost GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) или еще что-нибудь.

Например, на FreeImage загрузка битмапа выглядит так:

```
FIBITMAP *bitmap = FreeImage_Load(FIF_BMP, “picture.bmp”, BMP_DEFAULT);

if (bitmap) {    
    // Загружено
    // Отображаем в OpenGL 
    FreeImage_Unload(bitmap);
}
```

По стилистике кода DevIL достаточно хорошо подходит к OpenGL. А после того, как получен массив пискелей, он уже отображается с помощью приведенной выше функции glDrawPixels.

Comment: загрузить файл обычным образом? это как?

Comment: Берете, грузите, получаете массив цветов пикселей RGB размером width x height.

Comment: Вы действительно хотите чтобы я сделал както так:
Загрузить(Взять("картинка.джпг")); =)))
Я попросил исходники или пример(простои для понимания)! А вы мне алгоритм рассказываете...

Comment: можно всетаки пример opengl + devil я немогу понять как ето вывести ilGetData выдает помоему чтото не то =(

Comment: Ну поищите вы примеры по этой конкретной библиотеке. Их же полно везде всех цветов и вкусов. Запрос для гугла "[your library] example"